# cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Here is my code

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./dir
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
    - "5000:5000"
  redis:
   image: "redis:alpine"
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and then [edit] your question.**

Answer (score 3):

When you specify the following:

```
build: ./dir
dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

You are saying that the Dockerfile named `Dockerfile` is found under `./dir` folder relative to the compose file.

Docker compose is complaining that it couldn't find the Dockerfile under `./dir`. I suggest you use the following syntax:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: {DIRECTORY CONTAINING DOCKERFILE}
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
    - "5000:5000"
  redis:
   image: "redis:alpine"
```

Comment: After adding context I'm getting this error:   services.web.build contains an invalid type, it should be a string, or an object                                                      version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: 
    context: "C:/Users/dell/composetest/AmriteshComposetest/"
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
    - "5000:5000"
  redis:
   image: "redis:alpine"

Comment: My Docker Client Version is 17.10.0-ce and my Docker Server Version is 17.12.0-ce so what should be the .yml formate

Comment: @AmriteshKumar make sure you indent the yml file with 2 spaces. Post the compose file formated to the question.